# update transaction table data with new table id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables with following structure and data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department_New]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DepId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Department] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Department] ([Id], [Name]) 
VALUES (1, N'HR'), (2, N'IT'), (3, N'Account'), (4, N'Finance'), (5, N'Software') 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Department] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Department_New] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Department_New] ([Id], [Name]) 
VALUES (1, N'IT'), (2, N'HR'), (3, N'Software'), (4, N'Account'), 
       (5, N'iDontKnow'), (6, N'Finance') 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Department_New] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ON  

INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([Id], [DepId], [Name]) 
VALUES (1, 1, N'abc'), (2, 2, N'zxc'), (3, 1, N'xcv'),
       (4, 3, N'cvb'), (5, 4, N'vbn'), (6, 1, N'bnm'),
       (7, 3, N'asd'), (8, 3, N'sdf'), (9, 2, N'dfg'),
       (10, 4, N'fgh'), (11, 5, N'ghj'), (12, 5, N'hjk'),
       (13, 6, N'jkl'), (14, 6, N'qwe'), (15, 2, N'wre'),
       (16, 3, N'ert'), (17, 6, N'rty'), (18, 1, N'tyu') 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] OFF
```

As of now Employee table has old depId. I just want to update with new depId. I can not write for loop because employee table contains more than 1,000,000 rows of data.

What I have tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDepId
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalRecords INT
    DECLARE @I INT

    SELECT @I = 1

    SELECT @totalRecords = COUNT(DISTINCT DepId) FROM Employee

    DECLARE @DPID INT
    DECLARE @Id INT

    --drop table #Temp
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE #Temp; 

    CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        DepId INT
    )

    INSERT INTO #Temp 
        SELECT DISTINCT DepId  
        FROM Employee 
        ORDER BY DepId

    WHILE (@I <= @totalRecords)
    BEGIN
        SET @DPID = (SELECT DepId FROM #Temp WHERE Id = @I)
        EXEC UpdateDepByDepId @DPID

        SELECT @I = @I + 1
    END
    DROP TABLE #Temp
 END

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDepByDepId
    @DepId INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DepIdNew INT
    SET @DepIdNew = (SELECT Id FROM Department_New 
                     WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Department WHERE id = @DepId))

    SELECT @DepIdNew AS NewDepId, @DepId AS OldDepId

    IF ISNULL(@DepIdNew, 0) <> 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Employee 
        SET DepId = @DepIdNew 
        WHERE DepId = @DepId
    END
 END
```

But it is not working for me. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use an `update` and `from`:

```
update e
    set depid = dn.id
    from employee e join
         department d
         on e.depid = d.id join
         department_new dn
         on dn.name = d.name;
```

Comment: This is assigning `department_new.id` to each employee -- based on matching department names.  That appears to be what you are asking for.